# Passing data through events to adhere to the Tell-Don't-Ask principle?

Tags: c#, mvp, design-principles, event-handling

In my little WinForm app, intended to practice as a hobbyist, I'm using this code to pass data from the View to its Presenter:

```csharp
public event Action<object, string, string?>? SearchInAlbums;

        private void Btn_SearchInAlbums_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbSearchContext.SelectedValue.ToString()))
                SearchInAlbums?.Invoke(this, Txt_Search.Text, cmbSearchContext.SelectedValue.ToString());
        }
```

Then in the listener of this event, the Presenter, I can write code like this:

```csharp
        public void OnSearchInAlbums(object? sender, string searchPhrase, string? tableName)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName))
            {
                _albumList = _albumRepository.GetAlbumsByValue(searchPhrase, tableName);
                SetGridViewBindingSource();
            }
            else
            {
                _mainView.Message =
                    "No records were affected: the table name was NULL or EMPTY (no table name)";
            }
        }
```

This way this consumer (Presenter), doesn't have to ask for data - instead it gets it and then tells the Repository what to do with it. This way, in my mind, I have enforced the "Tell Don't Ask" principle.

But, I see nobody using code like:

```csharp
public event Action<object, string, string?>? SearchInAlbums;
```

Instead, they all use:

```csharp
public event EventHandler SearchInAlbums; //or something similar
```

By doing the latter, the presenter is *forced* to ask for data from the view and therefore the TDA principle has been broken. I'm a hobby-learner, so I don't know. What is the take by more experienced programmers? Am I actually doing things right here? Or am I using concepts wrong?

Teachers on YouTube always **ask for data** from the View of the Presenter, totally ignoring the TDA principle. Maybe that's normal in this case. But I wouldn't know why as it strikes me as unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But, I see nobody using code like:
>
> ```
>  public event Action<object, string, string?>? SearchInAlbums;
> ```

> Instead, they all use:
>
> ```
>  public event EventHandler SearchInAlbums; //or something similar
> ```
>
> By doing the latter, the presenter is forced to ask for data from the view and therefore the TDA principle has been broken.

Em, no. If you create a special SearchEventHandler with specific event args, like

```
public delegate void SearchEventHandler(object sender, SearchEventArgs e);
```

then you can pass all the data you like in the `SearchEventArgs` object and implement "tell don't ask" just as with a delegate declared by the `Action` syntax.

Note `Action<...>` was introduced  with .Net Fw 3.5, whilst `EventHandler` is much older, it was available already in .Net Fw 1.1 and is still used extensively inside Winforms itself. That is probably the reason why you find more examples with the `EventHandler` syntax. Today, I guess I would prefer `Action<object, string, string?>` when it helps to avoid boilerplate code, and when I don't need a uniform implementation where each handler derives from `EventHandler`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. 
Technically there's no need to avoid a custom 
`event Action<CustomArgsClass>` 
instead of using 
`event EventHandler<CustomArgsClass>`
 . Though I will encapsulate data so that I don't have to change signatures when expanding the data. So no 
`event Action<T1, T2, t3...>`
. Those parameters don't communicate either on top of aforementioned problem. Since everybody is using 
`EventHandler<>`
, so will I unless I need a return type. I.e. 
`Func<ArgsClass, ReturnType>`.

Answer (score 1):

> Teachers on YouTube always ask for data from the View within the Presenter totally ignoring the TDA principle

Well, maybe you took TDA a bit too far. *Tell don't ask* is a motto for us to improve the cohesion and encapsulation of the components. For example

```js
class GridView {
  public visible: true;
  public enabled: true;
  public doSomething(): void { .... }
}

class Presenter {
  private grid: GridView;
  public doSomething(): void {
     //breaking TDA: poor encapsulation and asking for info the grid already knows.
     if(this.grid.visible && this.grid.enabled){
        this.grid.doSomeThing();
     }
  }
}
```

Would be better if

```js
class GridView {
  private visible: true;
  private enabled: true;
  //high cohesion and encapsulation
  public doSomething(): void { 
     if(this.visible && this.enabled){
       //then ...
     } 
     //otherwise ...
  }
}

class Presenter {
  private grid: GridView;
  public doSomething(): void {
     //Compliant with TDA, the presenter is telling "grid", to do something
     this.grid.doSomething();
  }
}
```

> Am I actually doing things right here? Or am I using concepts wrong?

Technically, it's correct, but you might not have weighed the pros and cons of each solution. Essentially, this code is neither taking 40h/week of your time nor under the same pressure as a real-world project (frequent, unexpected and WTF changes).

If I got it right, `EventHandler SearchInAlbums` seems more convenient because extending the event handling to custom events only takes you to extend `EventArg` vs changing signatures, which is in many cases a considerable drawback.

In other words, passing Event-related data is fine using a derived class from EventArgs

Comment: I may have taken TDA to far. The question remains whether it's wise to use events like this to pass data around. I think it's an elegant method. In fact, instead of creating a DTO (our previous example where you were there) I first implemented a `RecordToEditEventArg : EventArgs` to pass all of the data of an album record to the presenter. But then I was told I wasn't allowed to do that. But when events can't be used like that, I feel we're missing out. That's where my question comes in: making sure I'm not missing something high-level like unit-testing problems or something.

Comment: Ok! I see it now. [It might interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431359/event-action-vs-event-eventhandler)

Comment: Yes, excellent find. Thank you. So my initial take, deriving from `EventArgs` to pass relevant event data was the right choice indeed. Maybe I should abandon YouTube and come here more often. I've entered a phase where I'm more interested in design issues than coding fundamentals.

Comment: @Valmont youtube tutorials are good at "how I do X with Y **for dummies**".  For learning, worth spending some money on e-learning platforms because of the content (more variety and sometimes more advanced). S.E. for everything else. Regarding blogs of random people (who probably did copy-paste from other blogs), avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: Yuppers, learning that. Soon I will refactor my test project and then it's off to learning XUnit. Then I will be faced with my design choices. I bought an introductory course into XUnit and unit testing. But I couldn't wait to have a few burning questions answered. Can you add the "answer"? I'll accept it again. The obvious answer is that passing Event-related data is fine using a derived class from EventArgs. That's the whole point of it.

Comment: @valmont Better now?